# how to solve 192-2a^2-a=m(6a+1)?

Tags: number-theory

how to solve $192-2a^2-a=m(6a+1)$ ?

or written as $(192-2a^2-a) \equiv 0$ (mod $6a+1$)

how to calculate the integer values of $a < 41$ ?

thanks

to understand that serving:

http://www.albericolepore.org/lepore-primality-test-and-factorization-polynomial-complexity/

Comment: $41$ is a small number, check all $0 < a < 42$ and get $a \in \{1,2,3,15,22,41\}$

Comment: @gammatester how did you calculated?

Comment: I do not understand your question, you should know how to calculate them
e.g. $a=3 \Rightarrow 192-2a^2-a = 171,\quad 6a+1=19,\quad 171 \pmod {19}\equiv 0$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As $(6a+1,3)=1$

$(6a+1)|(192-2a^2-a)\iff(6a+1)|3(192-2a^2-a)$

Now $\dfrac{3(192-2a^2-a)}{6a+1}=\dfrac{576-2a}{6a+1}-a$

Similarly, $(6a+1)|(576-2a)\iff(6a+1)|3(576-2a)$

$\implies$ we need $3\cdot576+1$ must be divisible by $6a+1$

Comment: $$1729=7\cdot13\cdot19$$

Comment: how to calculate the integer values of a<41 ?there's another way?

Comment: @AlbericoLepore, See which factors of $1729$ are $<41$

Comment: Thus, it needed to calculate the factors of 247.

Comment: @Alberico, $6a+1<6\cdot41+1$ So, $6a+1$ can be $7,13,19,7\cdot13 ,7\cdot19$

Comment: visit http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408851/lepore-primality-test-what-is-the-complexity